# Why are the discriminant axes in linear discriminant analysis (LDA) not orthogonal?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, discriminant-analysis, eigenvalues

This may be a quite silly question and please correct me if I'm wrong.

The discriminants (discriminant axes) are essentially eigenvectors of $\mathrm{Cov}_\mathrm{within}^{-1} \mathrm{Cov}_\mathrm{between}$, so why  are they not orthogonal?

I've found a lot of papers stating they have made improvements to make LDA orthogonal... but I don't get why it's not orthogonal in the first place.

Comment: Because if matrices A and B are both symmetric, the product AB is not necessarily symmetric. And orthogonality of eigenvectors only holds for symmetric matrices.

Comment: (But reasonable question, +1.)